# How to resize and overlay, in C#, 2 images using some points as reference

Tags: c#, system.drawing

I have 2 Bitmap (bmpA and bmpB) and in each I drawn a Line between 2 Points.
These lines have different length.

First:
I want to scale bmpB so that the line drawn in it have to be the same of the length drawn in the bmpA.

Second:
I want to overlay the two Bitmap and I want that exactly the points on the line in the bmpA overlap exactly the line in the bmpB.

I hope it's clear this explanation.

Comment: Have you considered using OpenCV for this task?

Comment: @CoolBots no because I don't know this library.

Comment: Graphics.ScaleTransform and RotateTransform should do the job.